# Choose which option is selected on pageload of razor html.dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdownlistfor created with razor that displays 2 option : "show" or "hide" and they have a respective value of "0" and "1".

```
 if (Model.Valeur == 0)
 {
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Valeur,
      new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "Show", Selected = true },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Hide" },
      }, new { @class = "myselect" })
 }
 else
 {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Valeur,
     new List<SelectListItem> {
     new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "Show" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Hide",  Selected = true },
     }, new { @class = "myselect" })
 }
```

The if condition I made can set the right value on page load, but I was wondering if there was a way to set the selected value with a parameter or another option

Any Information would be gladly aprreciated.

Comment: i think it will be selected when you pass the value without condition

Comment: The Valuer property have several values, or this property only have values 0 or 1?

Comment: the value property of m can be either 1 or 0 and i want to show to the user the selected option according to it

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Valeur, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "Show" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Hide" }, }, new { @class = "myselect" })` - no `if` block required, and no `Selected` property (which is ignored when binding to a property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use shorthand if to determine which option is selected.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Valeur,
 new List<SelectListItem> {
 new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "Show", Selected = Model.Valeur == 0 },
 new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Hide", Selected = Model.Valeur != 0 },
 }, new { @class = "myselect" })
```

Comment: You don't need to use the ternary operator here, instead you can use `Model.Valeur == 0` and `Model.Valeur != 0`; they both will return true or false on their own.

Comment: this works perfectly for my needs so thanks, the only change I made is I removed the ternary operator as @Vaterrenanburg said

Comment: @Vaterrenanburg your right, just use the right number (0 or 1) and ignore the `? true : false`  part

Comment: Bare in mind that mixing logic and presentation is not a good idea. The construction of the DropDownList values should be done in the ViewModel or in the Controller if the items are loaded dynamically.

Comment: The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a model property - its just pointless to include it